# Protractor E2E and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm having trouble figuring out how to target elements in our single-page application.

I'm testing mostly authenticated pages, so the data is being mocked for protractor using: `ngMockE2E` and `$httpBackend`

Let's say there are 4 pages/views: *Home* | *About* | ***Settings*** | *Sign out*

The ***Settings*** page structure is roughly:

```
<div ng-view class="ng-scope">
  <div class="row ng-scope" ng-controller="SettingsCtrl as ctrl">
    <h1>Settings Main Page</h1>
    <div ng-if="show.more">
      <a href="#/more/info">More Info</a>
      [...]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you click the *more info* link, the view will change to that page where the only major difference is in the `ng-controller`.

```
<div ng-view class="ng-scope">
  <div class="row ng-scope" ng-controller="SettingsCtrl">
    <h2>Settings More Info Page</h2>
    [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

In protractor I cannot figure out how to access the elements within the **more info page** - but I can locate the elements on the **main settings** page just fine.

For example:

```
var main_title = element(by.tagName('h1')).isPresent();
expect(main_title).toBe(true); // Will return true

var moreInfo_title = element(by.tagName('h2')).isPresent();
expect(moreInfo_title).toBe(true); // Will return false
```

Why can't I access elements within a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to *wait for the [presence](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) of the `h2` element*:

```
// click "More info"

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var moreInfo_title = element(by.tagName('h2'));  

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(moreInfo_title), 5000);

expect(moreInfo_title.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try clicking the link then check to see if the more info title exists.

```
var main_title = element(by.tagName('h1')).isPresent();
expect(main_title).toBe(true);

var link = element(by.linkText('More Info'));
link.click().then(function() {
   var moreInfo_title = element(by.tagName('h2')).isPresent();
   expect(moreInfo_title).toBe(true);
});
```